# Getting free space percent on multiple servers on different drive letters with powershell

Tags: powershell, wmi

I have some servers where i need to monitor the free space percentage with powershell.

For one Drive for one server its like that:

```
$size = ([wmi]"\\appsrv02\root\cimv2:Win32_logicalDisk.DeviceID='c:'").Size
$free = ([wmi]"\\appsrv02\root\cimv2:Win32_logicalDisk.DeviceID='c:'").FreeSpace
Write-Output ($free/$size).ToString("P0")
```

Sure, i could go about and repeat code and create a big script, but i "feel" it wrong 100%.

So how i would go about having n Servers that i want to check the free space and in different drives per server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Get-WMIObject` to poll the servers for disk information.

```
get-wmiobject win32_logicaldisk -filter "DriveType=3" -computername server1,server2|select-object -property systemname, deviceid, size, freespace, volumename
```

Comment: This seems that goes to the right direction of getting the data in a nice way. But afterwards how i keep my code D.R.Y ? I mean do you think of a way with arrays(maybe) that i could automate the different drive per server requirement?

Comment: Run it and check the output for yourself - it doesn't require that you select *any* drive letters specifically, it returns *all* local & mapped network drives that are present on each server.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a script that does that. Essentially I used a nested loop:

```
Foreach ($server in $serverlist) {

    $Disks = get-wmiobject Win32_LogicalDisk -computername $Server -Filter “DriveType = 3”

    Foreach ($Disk in $Disks) {

    Write-Output $server " = " $Disk.Freespace
    }
}
```

Comment: What i need is combination of server and letter. for example server1-c:, server2:e:, server3:c,d e.t.c

Comment: $Drive.DeviceID lists the drive letter. So your output would be something like: $server ": " $Drive.DeviceID " = " $Drive.Freespace